# Sorting Mixed Arrays and Objects by Key in PHP

Tags: php

I have an object / array that looks like this:

```
$methods = 
    Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [total] => 5.32
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [total] => 14.16
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [total] => 2.89
            )

    )
```

I want to sort the entire thing in ascending order by `total` I've tried usort with a cmp function and uasort, but I can't get it to work, one function complains that it's an object while the other complains it's an array.

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: `I've tried usort with a cmp function`.  Can you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 3):

You can use usort with a closure as of PHP 5.3 to accomplish this

```
usort($methods, function($a, $b) { return $a->total - $b->total; });
```

Pre-PHP 5.3 you have to defined your function separately and pass it in as a string.

```
if(!function_exists("totalSorter")){
  function totalSorter($a, $b){
    return $a->total - $b->total;
  }
}
usort($methods, "totalSorter");
```

Comment: +1 Eyeliner > oneliner > all.

Comment: I'm getting the error: `Warning: usort() [function.usort]: The argument should be an array`

Comment: The first argument should be your array see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//Initializing everything.
$obj1 = new stdClass();
$obj1->total = 5.32;

$obj2 = new stdClass();
$obj2->total = 14.16;

$obj3 = new stdClass(); 
$obj3->total = 2.89;

$methods = [$obj1, $obj2, $obj3];
//Make sure everything is setup correctly.
var_dump($methods);

//Magic
usort($methods, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a === $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $a > $b ? 1 : -1;
});

//Ta-da~
var_dump($methods);
```